# Can't remember the password for an old Apple ID and I'm not getting the password renew email?

Tags: itunes, email, apple-id, password, authorization

For some reason, iTunes has suddenly decided it won't let me sync tunes onto my ipod which were bought with an old Apple ID (even though the email account is still active and linked to the new Apple ID) and is saying my laptop (which I've been using for years) isn't authorized with that old Apple ID?

I can't remember the password for the old apple id. If I go to the login screen and click on "forgotten password" it says it will email me with a link to change the password but no email ever arrives in that account so I'm completely stuck.

Has anyone else experienced this problem?

Comment: you need to wait a bit with the email, and check your junk folder as well.

Comment: Thanks for the help.... I always keep my junk folder clear so it's definitely not in there. I tried this a couple of times about a week ago and no email yet......  :-(

Comment: You've given me an idea..... the old talktalk email address has been being redirected to my newer email account for years. I wonder where junk for the old account goes? I don't suppose that gets diverted to the new one? So I tried to get into the old account but talk talk (AOL) says it can't help me with a password as it was set up by another provider e.g. apple/google etc. Not sure where to go now! What I don't understand is why it's suddenly become a problem on itunes? Maybe something to do with changes they have made for sharing in the cloud? V.frustrating!

Comment: It sounds like you have 2 appleid's, the newer one having the the old email address listed as an alternate email for the new appleID.   Doing this doesn't "merge" the appleid's.   Go to iforgot.apple.com and see if you can figure out or reset the password for the Original appleId.   Once you have access to both you can probably combine them by setting up family sharing.